# Ramayana and Mahabharata Epics characters language interaction

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana

I would like to know in both the Holy Epics Ramayana and Mahabharata, the characters interaction were in which language/s?

I mean Lord Rama interacting with Lakshmana.

I mean Lord Krishna interacting with Bheeshma.

Is it Sanskrit? If it is Sanskrit, how old is this Great Language?

Comment: I have not seen mention of any other language except Sanskrit. I believe it has to be Sanskrit.